# How to include filter in query in haystack?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I cant figure out whats the simplest way to pass a filter to a query set from the urls.py file without having to write a new view. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().exclude(active = False)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    .....
    (r'^search/', include('haystack.urls'), {'searchqueryset':sqs}),

)
```

Input much appreciated!

Comment: what would the filter you are trying to add look like.  You've already filtered the queryset once...

Comment: Well, that code actually does not work, the filter is that one (active = False). So I am wondering if thats the right way of doing things in general (filter in the urls.py then pass query set to default view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason why the filter was not working is because I was using the Simple backend, which apparently does not support that kind of filter.
Problem was solved when I moved to using sorl.